# Browser support for CSS width 1000px

Tags: css, browser, width

**Are there any wildy used browsers that doesn't support width 1000px plus right scroll?**

**NOTE: With "support" I mean "if it will support 1000px width without creating a horizontal scroll in the bottom" (sorry for not explaining this in the beginning)**

What about IE7 for example?

I don't want to get the bottom scroll...

I know it might look bad on some 1024 screens if there is no space on the side.

**I am adding an example so you better will understand:**

The reason for asking is beceause I don't want to get a horizontal scroll on my website in widly used browsers. I don't have any old IE version installed, so I cant test it myself.

Note that the 3000px height div will cause a vertical scroll to the right... So the "browser window width" have to be at least 1000px in width for it to work (1024 minus right scroll (minus left border))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
<div style="width:1000px;height:3000px">Will this div creat a horizontal scroll bar in any widly used browser, with window size of 1024 x 768px <? What about Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the answers suggest, your question makes no sense.  All browsers 'support' pages of (practically) unlimited size.

Comment: I ahve updated the question. Does it make more sense now (sorry for not being able to ask question in the right way)?

Comment: Don't design web pages to 'work' at a size you decide. It is the user's decision what size the window (and therefore page) is.

Comment: Cant believe no one understands my question and the reason for asking the question. I must be very bad at asking questions. Will try to make it better (last try).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 960 pixels is the widely accepted standard for website layouts, but 980 is also common. 1000 may be a few pixels too many.

Comment: 998px is the maximum safe width for old browsers. Tough 1000px will work without horizontal scroll on most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

They all do, it's more of a matter of which monitors users have. Most sites use 960px-wide, mainly because it works well with 1024-wide monitors, and it is divisible by many factors, making it east to have balanced multi-column layouts.

You can safely go up to about 980px.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you know if 1000px-wide and 3000px-height layout works for a 1024 screen in IE 7 and IE 8? I mean are you shore it works?

Comment: Thats what I tought :( Any one with a IE7 and IE8 version that can confirm this?

Comment: @Hakan: What we're saying is that it will work in *any* browser, it has nothing to do with the browser. It has everything to do with the *user's screen/window size*. I often times un-mazimize my window and resize it really small to see how it would look in a tiny window, to make sure it doesn't break etc.

Comment: I know it will work in any browser. What I don't know is if it will create a horizontal scroll. Thats what I mean with support. If it creates a horizontal scroll it doesn't suppport 1000px width div tags. Sorry for using the word "support".

Answer (score 0):

In fact doesnt matter which browser you are using, but the screen resolution and the size of the browser window.

At 1024x768 resolution, with width = 980px (and no side padding) it will not create scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

All browsers support whatever width you want.

What you really care about is screen resolution and the actual viewport width of the current browser window.  For example, my 2 screens gives me an effective screen width of 1920+1920=3840 pixels, but I never maximize my browser so the viewport is more like 800 pixels wide.
(I hate 960px grids)

See the article [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) for discussion of making a truly width-adaptive layout.

---

The answer doesn't change with your update to the question. The answer is still:

```
All browsers support whatever width you want.
```

If you have enough screen space available to make a browser window wide enough, it will display any width page without scrollbars.

> What about IE7 for example?

Since I can stretch my IE 7 window (or IE 8 or 9) to be 3000px wide, IE 7 will display a 1000px wide page without a horizontal scrollbar. Therefore, IE 7 "supports" a width of 1000px without a scrollbar. In that sense, ***All browsers support whatever width you want.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question, please have a look. I also go with two 1920px screens. It's nice ;)